# PHP Eclipse - git staging

Tags: php, eclipse, git, egit

I am using Eclipse Luna for PHP developers for my PHP project and eGit plugin. When I open Git Staging view in eclipse, there are some files which are ready for staging but I did not change. When I open them for compare - there is no difference. Clicking on "Reset" to discard those changes does not removes those files from staging. So my question is, what may cause files to be considered as modified and ready for staging although they are not modified ?

Answer (score 0):

Line endings might have changed, but this can be seen in compare view - all lines are marked as different, but there are no other visible changes. You can make eclipse display white spaces to make verification easier. Some Eclipse tasks and other programs convert line endings to Windows silently.

Another option may be that execute bit is set on those files, you are on Windows and have `core.filemode` flag set to `true`. EGit will show you that files in the repo are executable, but in your working copy aren't. Reset the flag to false to get rid of that.

If your problem isn't caused by any of the above, describe the case in more detail and check if command line `git status` also shows changes.